# Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart, back4app

my problem is that i want to display the server data in a table, the data appears in the console but cannot be displayed but got one of type 'Null'

I show you the piece of code that allows me to display the data in the table

[image: 1]

and this is what appears in the console

[image: 2]

Comment: Some fields that are coming from the server may have a null value. Consider using a null check before rendering the UI.

Comment: Glad that I could be of help. :D